# Where does the documentation point to a list of values for the loss property of the compile function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following the [Tensorflow documentation for creating a simple neural network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification).  One of the steps is

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I look at the documentation for the `loss` parameter, it says

> **loss**: String (name of objective function), objective function or
>   tf.losses.Loss  instance. See tf.losses. If the model has multiple
>   outputs, you can use a  different loss on each output by passing a
>   dictionary or a list of losses. The  loss value that will be minimized
>   by the model will then be the sum of all  individual losses.

Based on this documentation of the `compile` function, how would I find a list of the strings and/or objective functions that I can pass for the `loss` parameter?  I found the `tr.keras.losses` that has the objective functions by Googling, but it seems like there should be a link or mention of that in the documentation for `Sequential.compile`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is Keras code, so you'll find the list of available loss functions in the Keras doc: https://keras.io/losses/